# Is this sequence of functions pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence of functions defined by:

$$f_n(x) := n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}.$$

My question is, is this sequence of functions pointwise bounded but not uniformly bounded? For context, I have just come across these definitions in my RA class, however, no example was given to *separate* the two concepts.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove this?  Can you do pointwise bounded?  Can you do uniformly bounded?  In this forum, you should provide your own attempts!  It is best to help you learn.

Comment: Yes that's a valid example. This is $(f_n(x))_{n}$ is bounded for every $n$ (since it has finite non zero elements). But $(f_n)$ is not uniformly bounded, since for every $M>0$, $\exists n>M$ and $x$ small enough, so that $x\in [0, 1/n)$, so that $f_n(x) = n > M$.

Comment: @GEdgar My apologies! Typically I do post my attempted solutions, however, this was more of a...do I have the definitions correct, type of question.

Comment: @alphaomega Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointwise bounded means that for each point $x$, $f_n(x)$ is a bounded sequence. Indeed, for any $x$, there is some $n$, starting from which $x$ is not in the given interval, and so from that point onwards we have that $f_n(x)=0$, and so the sequence is bounded (as it only attains a finite number of values).

Uniformly bounded means that there is a uniform bound on all such sequences $f_n(x)$ - there is some $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|<M$ for all $x$ and for all $n$. To show that the sequence is not uniformly bounded, show that $f_n(x)$ can get arbitrarily large as $n$ grows, if you pick the right $x$. Can you find a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ gets arbitrarily large?

Comment: Maybe letting $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Dalton Exactly - you get the sequence $f_n=n$, which is unbounded (so there cannot be a uniform bound for all $x$).